# which design better when use foreign key instead of a string to store a list of id

Tags: database-design, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is using multiple foreign keys seperated by commas wrong, and if so, why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/is-using-multiple-foreign-keys-seperated-by-commas-wrong-and-if-so-why)

I'm building online examination system. I have designed to table, `Question` and `GeneralExam`. The table `GeneralExam` contains info about the exam like name, description, duration,... Now I would like to design table `GeneralQuestion`, it will contains the id of questions belongs to a `general exam`.

Currently, I have two idea to design `GeneralQuestion` table:

1. It will have two column: general_exam_id, question_id.
2. It will have two column: general_exam_id, list_question_ids(string/text).

So, I would like to know which designing is better, or Pros and Cons of each designing. I'm using Postgresql database.

Comment: I wouldn't even really care about the performance - but if you use just a plain old *list of strings* - how do you **ensure data integrity**?? How can you make sure only valid ID's will be stored?? That's what foreign keys are for - **ensuring data integrity** (not performance....)

Comment: @marc_s I have replied on SO, sorry for make question on many sites, because I think some people only care about some site :)

Comment: See this question: **[Is using multiple foreign keys seperated by commas wrong, and if so, why?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/is-using-multiple-foreign-keys-seperated-by-commas-wrong-and-if-so-why)**

Comment: And at SO: **[Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)**

Comment: I have to repeat this as well: do ***not*** store comma separated values in a single column. Just don't.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for advice, i designed table in first solution, but suddenly solution 2 coming in mind, so i just wonder maybe it better when it take less rows :) but now I know this is wrong, absolute wrong.

Comment: Don't worry about 100, 1000 or even 10'000 rows - any decent RDBMS will just laugh at such a number of rows..... being able to enforce data integrity is ***MUCH*** more important than having a few lookup tables with a few hundred or a few thousand rows more..... having dealt with loads of crappily designed databases *without* data integrity, I cannot stress enough just how important data integrity (and thus referential integrity on a database level) is .....

Comment: @marc_s thanks so much :), i'm still be student, so maybe i had a stupid question, thanks to you helped  me have more experience :D

Comment: @Kien: No reason to apologize. It's better to ask questions when one isn't sure. And don't misunderstand if this question is closed. That shouldn't stop you from asking more of them :)

Answer (score 1):

As ypercube and marc_s pointed out, it's best to have a 2-column "mapping" table to store which questions are used by which general exams.

This approach provides the following benefits:

- Foreign Keys can then be used to ensure data integrity
- Queries are much easier to write (eg: find all general exams that use question 17)
- Extending the database schema at a later date (to support new features) will be much easier
- The schema will be easier to understand by new/other developers/DBAs since it confirms to best practice