# Should I create a new table for store information of an associated object with object need to create

Tags: database-design

I'm not sure if topic can get you understand what I want to explain.
Follow guide in my [old question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28792/which-design-better-when-use-foreign-key-instead-of-a-string-to-store-a-list-of), now I have these tables and its columns:

- Course: `name,...`
- Topic: `name, course_id`
- Question: `content, topic_id`
- GeneralExam: `name, description, semester, number_question (total number of questions of general exam), duration, used (boolean), user_id, course_id`
- GeneralQuestion: `general_exam_id, question_id`

To sum up association:

- Course - Topic: one-to-many
- Topic - Question: one-to-many
- Course - GeneralExam: one-to-many
- Question - GeneralExam: many-to-many, join table: GeneralQuestion

Now, When creating new General Exam (GE) for a course, I want to specific a number of questions for each topic of that course, so that I can get questions for that GE ( I want to do(specific) it on form, I had a form for create new GE now). So, should I create new table to store a number of questions of each topic of course when creating new GE? If I should, how table I should design?

I image table I should design will like this (I can't get name of table now):

**NameOfTable: general_exam_id, course_id, topic_id, number_question**

Is this table good?

Answer (score 1):

If the number of questions for each topic on each course varies from one General Exam to another, then yes, you want a structure like this (which is pretty much what you have):

```
NumberQuestions:
GE_ID int FK
Course_ID int FK
Topic_ID int FK
MaxQuestions int
```

Comment: yes, every GE has different number of questions of course's topics. Ah, maybe I don't need Course_ID, because it's already in GE table, right?