# select items with one or more specified tags

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.
One table holds tags:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) COMMENT='';
INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'tag one'),
(2, 'tag two'),
(3, 'tag three'),
(4, 'tag four'),
(5, 'tag five');
```

Other table holds items, where each item has zero or more tags (their IDs) separated by comma:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `tags` text NOT NULL
) COMMENT='';
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `name`, `tags`) VALUES
(1, 'first item',   '2,4'),
(2, 'second item',  ''),
(3, 'third item',   '1'),
(4, 'fourth item',  '1,3,4');
```

How do I select only those items which have at least one of the wanted, say `(2,3)` tags?

Comment: How many tags do you have?more than 5?

Comment: About 200 and number will rise. And number of items goes to thousands.

Comment: Is modifying the table an option?Replace tag.name with numbers.

Comment: I would rather not modify current tables' layout. What do you mean by replace tag.name with numbers?

Comment: If you address those repetitive "tag " words in each tag name, than those are just example tag names. The real ones are more various of course. ;) And still, those are just names. I reference tags by their ID.

Comment: The `tags.name` column is fine. What is wrong is the comma separated list. This should be replaced with an intermediate table. then you will be properly referencing the `tags(id)`. Now you can have silly values in the `items(tags)` column, values like `'1,2,3,1,1,2,2,5789'` where a tag is "referenced" twice or a tag that doesn't exist is referenced.

Comment: Yeah,sorry I completely overlooked tags id,I was fixated on name for some reason.

Comment: @ypercube I check tags for repetition when saving the item, so it is not an issue. And I believe non-existing tag isn't an issue either because I also check if it is used in any of items before I delete the tag.

Comment: Please read this at DBA.SE: **[Is using multiple foreign keys separated by commas wrong, and if so, why?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/is-using-multiple-foreign-keys-separated-by-commas-wrong-and-if-so-why/17810#17810)**

Comment: and a similar question at SO: **[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)** about why this is a really bad idea.

Comment: In the mean time - until you improve the design - you can use the `FIND_IN_SET()` and similar functions to solve your query problems but the efficiency will be decreasing as the tables grow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use FIND_IN_SET function

```
SELECT * FROM items 
JOIN tags 
ON FIND_IN_SET(tags.id,items.tags)
WHERE tags.id IN(2,3)
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dace83/3)

Comment: Thank you. I knew FIND_IN_SET and JOIN are the way to go, I just don't know why I didn't put those two together. :)