# A many-to-many relationship

Tags: database-design, many-to-many, undefined-relations

I'm designing a simple database and have a question regarding a relationship. So far, I have users, books, highlights and bookmarks. The relationship rules are as follows:

1. Each user may 'subscribe' to a book.
2. Each book may have many users 'subscribed' to it.
3. Each user can have highlights and bookmarks for the book(s) he has 'subscribed' to.

The schema I have so far:

[image]

I'm having a problem with the last relation. What I have thought about so far was to use a single primary key instead of 2 keys acting as a composite key for the table `book_users` and then referencing that as a foreign key in the `highlights` and `bookmarks` table.

Another method that my friend recommended was to add another field called `additions` to the table `book_users` with a field of `TEXT` and storing the information in JSON format. The latter seems cleaner and I can't forsee any problems but I just want to confirm if this method is alright to implement.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What problem will the JSON idea solve? I can see only problems in the long run with that.

Comment: The attributes of 'highlights' and 'bookmarks' will be stored as JSON. That means, we can get rid of the two tables.

Comment: And why is having 2 tables a problem? Potentially you could have your whole database in one, single, huge, json document. Would that be better?

Comment: You can read this (and your friend): **[Is using multiple foreign keys separated by commas wrong, and if so, why?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/is-using-multiple-foreign-keys-separated-by-commas-wrong-and-if-so-why)**

Comment: And this as well: **[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first design is better with two additional table `highlights` and `bookmarks`.

In long run it will be difficult with design to save data in JSON format, Let say you need to search a bookmark or search a highlights, I am thinking what would be sql query for that. or Let say for page you need to show the highlights, How you will show that.

Even if somehow you solve above problem, performance issue will be a concern. The first design offers `indexes` and even with long run big tables data can fetched quickly.

Check the datatype of `id` column in table `books_users`, it would be `INT`,

Comment: So, something like [this](http://s4.postimg.org/igt6xmw7h/final_db.png)?

Comment: yes go with your design