# Join with comma separated values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a table `[CourseMaster]` LIKE

```
CourseId    CourseName
-----------------------
  01          ABC
  02          DEF
  03          GHI
  04          JKL
  05          MNO
  06          PQR
  07          STU
```

And I have another table `[StudentMaster]` for Student Details LIKE

```
ROLLNO  NAME    ADDRESS          Course
------------------------------------------------
12345   RAM     RAM ADDRESS      01,02,06                      
25695   HARI    HARI ADDRESS     02,06                         
89685   JEFF    JEFF ADDRESS     03,05,06,07                   
47896   DAISY   DAISY ADDRESS    03
```

Here I want to fetch the Student details with `CourseName`(Not `CourseId`).

If the values in `Course` is not comma separated than it would be very simple `query` to fetch the details with join.

As of my knowledge I can run two `queries` for the same result what I want, One query for fetching the details of student from `[StudentMaster]` to the front end. And other one for only fetching the `CourseName` from `[CourseMaster]` by corresponding `CourseId` through a loop.

But the fact I want the result by only one `query` rather than write two `queries` for this small task.

I guess it is 100% possible. And my expected result will look like:

```
ROLLNO  NAME    ADDRESS         Course
-------------------------------------------
12345   RAM     RAM ADDRESS     ABC,DEF,PQR                   
25695   HARI    HARI ADDRESS    DEF,PQR                       
89685   JEFF    JEFF ADDRESS    GHI,MNO,PQR,STU               
47896   DAISY   DAISY ADDRESS   GHI
```

Thank you and any valuable suggestion will be highly appreciate.

Comment: The best would be to normalize your tables and not store comma separated values: [Is using multiple foreign keys separated by commas wrong, and if so, why?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/is-using-multiple-foreign-keys-separated-by-commas-wrong-and-if-so-why/17810#17810)

Comment: yes i wonder if i can, but i am working on a existing project so unable to modify the structure sorry

Comment: After the normalisation you can always replace `[StudentMaster]` with a view and use triggers to be used by the current application(s) and then bit by bit change the code until you no longer need the current situation. Not beautiful but you end up with a better database.

Comment: That's very tough task for me

Comment: Can't I achieve the above requirement with my current database structure ?

Comment: Your predecessor saved some time with an idea that seemed good at the time, but now you are dealing the consequences.  It is never too late to fix a problem, you just have to convince your bosses that is really is worth the effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You really should have a junction table for the courses a student is taking, rather than jamming comma-separated values into a single tuple. If you think this is the last problem you'll have because of this sub-optimal design, you're in for a big surprise. You really should have the owners of this project go read up on normalization - yes it's painful to change your schema, but so is constantly dealing with the limitations of leaving it like it is.

Anyway, with that said, you need a split function. Since your comma-separated values are numeric, you can get away with a variation on my XML function; there are several others to choose from [in this blog post](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  CHAR(1) = ','
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

Now, your query is:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT s.ROLLNO, s.Name, s.Address, c.CourseId, c.CourseName
  FROM dbo.StudentMaster AS s
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(s.Course, default) AS f
  INNER JOIN dbo.CourseMaster AS c
  ON f.item = c.CourseId
)
SELECT ROLLNO, Name, Address, STUFF((
  SELECT ',' + CourseName FROM x AS x2 
  WHERE x2.ROLLNO = x.ROLLNO
  ORDER BY CourseId FOR XML PATH, 
  TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM x
GROUP BY ROLLNO, Name, Address;
```

Again, this is a complicated solution, and because of your inferior database structure, the next query you have to perform will be equally convoluted and cumbersome. There's a reason this type of design is argued against in just about every blog, essay, or book about the topic...

In more modern versions (SQL Server 2017 and above), you can combine `STRING_AGG()` and `STRING_SPLIT()` to make this a little simpler:

```
SELECT s.ROLLNO, s.NAME, s.ADDRESS, STRING_AGG(c.CourseName, ',')
  FROM dbo.StudentMaster AS s
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s.Course, ',') AS f
  INNER JOIN dbo.CourseMaster AS c
  ON f.value = c.CourseId
  GROUP BY s.ROLLNO, s.NAME, s.ADDRESS;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great suggestion. And now i am looking forward to optimize my database.

Comment: And I am testing your solution and will get back to you, Thank you again

Answer (score 5):

Same solution as the one provided by Aaron Bertrand when it comes to building the comma separated values but a bit different in connecting `CourseMaster.CourseId` with the values in `StudentMaster.Course`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d001/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
create table dbo.CourseMaster
(
  CourseId char(2),
  CourseName char(3)
);

create table dbo.StudentMaster
(
  ROLLNO char(5),
  NAME varchar(10),
  ADDRESS varchar(20),
  Course varchar(100)
);

insert into dbo.CourseMaster values
('01', 'ABC'),
('02', 'DEF'),
('03', 'GHI'),
('04', 'JKL'),
('05', 'MNO'),
('06', 'PQR'),
('07', 'STU');

insert into dbo.StudentMaster values
('12345', 'RAM',   'RAM ADDRESS',   '01,02,06'),                      
('25695', 'HARI',  'HARI ADDRESS',  '02,06'),                         
('89685', 'JEFF',  'JEFF ADDRESS',  '03,05,06,07'),                   
('47896', 'DAISY', 'DAISY ADDRESS', '03');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select SM.ROLLNO,
       SM.NAME, 
       SM.ADDRESS,
       (
       select ','+CM.CourseName
       from dbo.CourseMaster as CM
       where ','+SM.Course+',' like '%,'+CM.CourseId+',%'
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') as Course
from dbo.StudentMaster as SM;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d001/1/0)**:

```
| ROLLNO |  NAME |       ADDRESS |          Course |
|--------|-------|---------------|-----------------|
|  12345 |   RAM |   RAM ADDRESS |     ABC,DEF,PQR |
|  25695 |  HARI |  HARI ADDRESS |         DEF,PQR |
|  89685 |  JEFF |  JEFF ADDRESS | GHI,MNO,PQR,STU |
|  47896 | DAISY | DAISY ADDRESS |             GHI |
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get the list values from the `StudentMaster` table (and you can join against the results) would be to (with the help of a split string as mentioned earlier replies, and assuming that function returns a column called item for each list item):

```
SELECT ROLLNO, NAME, ADDRESS, item
FROM StudentMaster
CROSS APPLY fSplitString(Course);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select D.DATE,D.DESCP,
   (
   select ','+S.NAME
   from tb_schems as S
   where ',' + D.SCHME + ',' like '%,' + cast(S.id as nvarchar(20)) + ',%'
   for xml path(''), type
   ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') as SCHEME
from TB_DETAIL as D;
```