# Storing rows vs unique column values

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database that has the following structure:[image]

where the fields in `column1` and `column2` can take any value and where the `order` column indicates the order in which the original data was inserted. This table contains a lot of rows (with lots of duplicates) and I'm wondering whether there is a smarter way to store this data. Suppose that I were to create a unique id for each value per column and store the data like this:

[image]

Suppose that `n` is the number of rows in the first table and `u` the number of unique rows in the first table. If `u` is relatively large then the `order` column in the second table will have relatively short values in the `order` column fields, and if `u` is relatively large the fields in the `order` column in the second table will be quite wide. I would like to be able to compare the best storage method in both cases.

**Question:** I want to be able to compare these two tables to determine which storage method is better; is there a formula/method to find out how columns vs rows take up memory?

Comment: No, storing comma separated values is not proper design for a relational database. Just don't. And read this: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) Short answer: **Yes, it's really that bad.**

Comment: And a similar question, in our site: [Is using multiple foreign keys separated by commas wrong, and if so, why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/is-using-multiple-foreign-keys-separated-by-commas-wrong-and-if-so-why)

Answer (score 0):

Your first design is a better than your second design. Normally, one would want to avoid storing multiple values in a single column in an idiosyncratic format that requires parsing. If you do want to store multiple values in a single column, it would be best to use PostgreSQL's built-in array support for that. Do note, though, that for efficient querying, like with you idiosyncratic idea, you would then likely end up needing indexes on an expression.